# Sql Developer 2.1 query results window: turn off auto resizing?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I recently upgraded to Oracle Sql Developer 2.1   It's far better, but the query results window automatically makes itself really big each time I run a query, covering most of my worksheet.  Does anyone know a way to turn this off, so that it stays the same size when a query is run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pin next to the query results.  This forces the next query you run to open a new results window, but also keeps it from changing sizes.

Comment: The newer version that came out yesterday does not have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

2.1 is still Early Adopter, so I'd expect to see a few bugs like that. Best thing is to log them on the SQL Developer forum.